# Algorithm to compute decomposition of a union of sets to a disjoint union of intersections

Tags: algorithms, sets

A union of sets can be decomposed into a disjoint union of intersections. Rather than writing confusing notation, this is easiest to to see in an example of three sets. [image]

This clearly generalizes. If we want to calculate the disjoint pieces, we have to compute $2^n$ intersections, where $n$ is the number of sets.

However, if our sets were nested, i.e. $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq ... A_n$, we need only to compute $n$ intersections of the form $A_i \cap A_{i+1}^c$. The point is if we did our original exhaustive "binary search" computing $2^n$ intersections we would find that most of these intersections are empty, so we are wasting computations.

My question is, what if we had $n$ sets where the vast majority are nested, but a few aren't and we don't know which. Can we compute an $O(n)$ number of intersections to find the disjoint pieces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not $O(n)$.  Suppose $0.9n$ are nested and $0.1n$ are not nested (and are unrelated).  Then there can be at least $2^{0.1n}$ different pieces, which is not $O(n)$.

You can find the nesting structure in $O(n^2)$ time by testing all pairs of sets to see which are subsets of the other.